# detecting dropped items with core.async pub

Tags: clojure, core.async

I'm looking at using a shared `core.async` `pub` channel as the primary communication layer for my app as a way to introduce some indirection between components. I'm concerned about the behavior of `pub`, though, specifically the way that it silently drops items if there is no matching `sub` for a given topic. In a large system, this seems like it could be a real headache to debug. Is there any way to detect that an item got dropped, or at least to throw an exception in this case?

Comment: Why a pub opposed to a regular channel?

Comment: @AlejandroC. in order to enable routing messages to different components based on topic, and to enable multiple subscribers for the same message.

Comment: Provide a fallback topic (`:default`) in the topic-fn and always register a default sub handling that topic?

Comment: @glts , how would you know when to return the `:default` topic from `topic-fn`?

Answer (score 0):

No, it looks like it just gets dropped silently if there's no matching topic subscriber https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/2afc2dc5102f60713135ffca6fab993fb35809f0/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L879